# React native Textinput input max length value

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

How do you set such value? For example the number field must be less than 50.

how to use with maxLength={2} property,
how to validate it.. i want input number should be less than 50

here is my code..

```
 ShowMaxAlert = (EnteredValue) =>{
    this.setState({number: EnteredValue});
      if(EnteredValue > 50)
      {
        alert('Maximum number')
      }
}

<TextInput style={styles.input}
keyboardType={"numeric"}
underlineColorAndroid='#fff'
placeholder={'num'}
maxLength={2}
placeholderTextColor={'#ccc'}
onChangeText={ EnteredValue => this.ShowMaxAlert(EnteredValue) }
value={this.state.number} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The maxLength prop is used to validate the maximum length of the text that is entered, here your requirement is to validate against a max number. Your logic should be like below.

```
  ShowMaxAlert = (EnteredValue) => {
    if (EnteredValue < 50) {
         this.setState({number: EnteredValue});
    } else {
      alert('Maximum number');
    }
  };
```

Here the function will alert if the value is greater than 50, otherwise it will set the state which will update the value in the textbox.